# input type=button not validating

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, button, submission

HTML5 and jQuery with jQuery Mobile.
I want to use a button to submit a form so that an image can be included in it.

The form needs to be validated, too.

With the following, the form submits but is not validated. That is, if I leave a required form element blank, the form will submit (the alert box shows up).

HTML

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">

    [required elements here to validate]

    <button type="button" name="submit1" id="submit1"><img src="myimg" />Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
jQ('#submit1').click(function(event){
    jQ('#myform').submit(event);
    event.preventDefault();

    [more code here to run]

    alert('submitted');
});
```

Comment: Sorry - title should be "type=button".

Comment: Do you have a method that validates the form?  Normally one would call a validation method of some sort before calling `submit()` on the form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are triggering a form submit with `.submit()` before you call `event.preventDefault()`. Furthermore, you should only call `.submit()` conditionally when all validation is successful. Failing to have form submission be conditional upon successful validation will cause the browser to navigate away from the page without seeing any of the validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<script>
function submission() {
some code
return true;
}
</script>
<form id="myform" name="myform" onsubmit="return submission();">

[required elements here to validate]

<button type="button" name="submit1" id="submit1"><img src="myimg" />Submit</button>
</form>
jQ('#submit1').click(function(event){
jQ('#myform').submit(event);
});
```